# How to Add Cell Data to Unbound Column with Bound Columns without using For Each ? - VB NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Peace Everyone, I am currently having problems with this type of method on adding an unbound column on datagridview with bound columns. Because I cant use this type of method without having to use "for each statement", which I find very irritating already. Since I am trying to solve this by not asking on this site. But yeah, I give up already. So, here is my codes. Please help me.

```
'------------REFRESH DISPLAY------------'
Public Sub RefreshDaysDetails()
    '------------CONNECTION DATABASE------------'
    Dim connectionDaysDetails As New SqlConnection(_1LoginForm.connectionstring)
    '------------QUERY------------'
    sqlDaysDetails = "SELECT Date,CONVERT(varchar(15), TimeIn, 100) AS 'Time In',CONVERT(varchar(15), TimeOut, 100) AS 'Time Out',DATEPART(hour, WorkingHours) AS 'Working Hours'  FROM [3EmployeeAttendance] WHERE TimeOut IS NOT NULL AND TimeIn IS NOT NULL"
    '------------START CONNECTION------------'
    connectionDaysDetails.Open()
    '------------SQL------------'
    sCommandDaysDetails = New SqlCommand(sqlDaysDetails, connectionDaysDetails)
    sAdapterDaysDetails = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommandDaysDetails)
    sBuilderDaysDetails = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapterDaysDetails)
    sDsDaysDetails = New DataSet()



    sAdapterDaysDetails.Fill(sDsDaysDetails, "DaysDetails")
    sTableDaysDetails = sDsDaysDetails.Tables("DaysDetails")

    '------------SET OF BINDING SOURCE------------'
    DaysDetailsbindingsource.DataSource = sDsDaysDetails.Tables("DaysDetails")


    '------------CONNECTION DATABASE------------'
    Dim connectionDaysDetailsTwo As New SqlConnection(_1LoginForm.connectionstring)
    '------------QUERY------------'
    sqlDaysDetailsTwo = "SELECT DATEPART(hour,TimeIn) as 'TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn',DATEPART(hour,TimeOut) as 'TotalWorkingHoursTimeOut'  FROM [3EmployeeAttendance] WHERE TimeOut IS NOT NULL AND TimeIn IS NOT NULL "

    '------------START CONNECTION------------'
    connectionDaysDetailsTwo.Open()

    '------------SQL------------'
    sCommandDaysDetailsTwo = New SqlCommand(sqlDaysDetailsTwo, connectionDaysDetailsTwo)
    sAdapterDaysDetailsTwo = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommandDaysDetailsTwo)
    sBuilderDaysDetailsTwo = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapterDaysDetailsTwo)


    '------------CODES TO DISPLAY DATA TO TEXTBOXES------------'
    sCommandDaysDetailsTwo.Prepare()
    sDataReaderDaysDetailsTwo = sCommandDaysDetailsTwo.ExecuteReader()

    For Each row In sDataReaderDaysDetailsTwo
        TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn = sDataReaderDaysDetailsTwo.Item("TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn")
        TotalWorkingHoursTimeOut = sDataReaderDaysDetailsTwo.Item("TotalWorkingHoursTimeOut")
        While TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn < TotalWorkingHoursTimeOut
            TotalWorkingHours = TotalWorkingHours + 1
            TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn = TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn + 1
        End While
    Next


    '------------BINDS DGV TO THE EXISTING DATA------------'
    DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.DataSource = DaysDetailsbindingsource

    '------------CREATES DATA GRID VIEW TEXBOX COLUMN AND ADDS IT TO DATA GRID VIEW------------'
    Dim TotalWorkHoursextraColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
    With TotalWorkHoursextraColumn
        .Name = "TotalWorkHoursPerDay"
        .HeaderText = "Total Work Hours"
        .ReadOnly = True
    End With
    DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.Columns.Add(TotalWorkHoursextraColumn)


    '------------LOOP DGV TO CALCULATE TOTAL HOURS PER ROW------------'
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.Rows
        row.Cells("TotalWorkHoursPerDay").Value = CInt(TotalWorkingHours)
    Next

    '------------CLOSE CONNECTION------------'
    connectionDaysDetailsTwo.Close()



    '------------CLOSE CONNECTION------------'
    connectionDaysDetails.Close()
    '------------DATA BINDINGS------------'
    DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.DataSource = DaysDetailsbindingsource
    BNViewDaysDetailsForm.BindingSource = DaysDetailsbindingsource


    '------------DATA GRID VIEW SELECTION------------'
    DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.MultiSelect = False



End Sub
```

And this is the image output of the code above:

[image: ImageOutput]

As you see the Working Hours Column is okay, because that is from a bound column. but look at the unbound column named 'Total Work Hours' (I just named it 'Total Working Hours'. Because what I really need is the break down of the hours on each row.), the results are the same. all 15, because I cant properly execute my codes while having this code inside the for each statement.

```
 '------------LOOP DGV TO CALCULATE TOTAL HOURS PER ROW------------'
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.Rows
    row.Cells("TotalWorkHoursPerDay").Value = CInt(TotalWorkingHours)
Next
```

Are there any way to relate the row.Cells("TotalWorkHoursPerDay").Value = CInt(TotalWorkingHours) in my DGVViewDaysDetailsForm?

Because each time I removed the for each and just keep the row.Cells("TotalWorkHoursPerDay").Value = CInt(TotalWorkingHours)

I got error codes like: 
Cannot find the Parameter column name
Cannot add rows because the datagridview is bound
Column does not exist

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub dgv_CellValidating(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellValidating    

if e.RowIndex > -1 then
Dim dteValue1 as Date = DateTime.Parse(dgv.item("TotalWorkingHoursTimeIn", e.RowIndex).Value)
Dim dteValue2 as Date = DateTime.Parse(dgv.item("TotalWorkingHoursTimeOut", e.RowIndex).Value)
 dgv.Rows("TotalWorkHoursPerDay", e.RowIndex).Value = DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, dteValue1, dteValue2).ToString()
End if
```

Try the above code in the cell validating event. Hope this works

Comment: Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Item' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: Ok, there is another way of doing it. Ignore the DataReader loop. Altogether and derive the hours in cell_validate eventHandler. 
`For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DGVViewDaysDetailsForm.Rows
        row.Cells("TotalWorkHoursPerDay").Value = CInt(TotalWorkingHours)`
    Next`. Remove this and use the new answer above.

Comment: thanks for the help, but this solution doesn't work too.